# Several applications cannot write data files to sdcard

Tags: android, twitter, permissions

it bothered me long but today i decided to do something with it:
several applications malfunction on my HTC One S with Maximus HD Custom ROM(a stockish ROM with HTC Sense 5.0 ported from newer model), namely Twitter, Vkontakte official app and What'sApp.

Twitter won't download any photos(though text tweets are OK), What's App can't get photos either, and VK client cannot download music tracks.
When I checked the log I discovered messages like this

```
W/DiskLruCache( 9996): /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.twitter.android/cache/users is corrupt: /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.twitter.android/cache/users/journal: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied), removing
```

OR

```
D/vk      ( 8550): GET aHR0cDovL2NzMS01MHY0LnZrLWNkbi5uZXQvcDEvN2YyZTRiODA4ZjVkYWMubXAzP2V4dHJhPUczOEYxQnZoVnJsSldQSmNWME56bzllZWpqem5hbFRjdnpVMlJOMXRQQW91WHNHTU5qX19vYU9Lb1h0QU5oQWM0WmpmSlZZRUw4VEdoSXAwMVgtVnRlMU9Kanl3NHdfX18zNjU4OTZfX18zMjgwMTExMDE HTTP/1.1
D/vk      ( 8550): Host: 127.0.0.1:48329
D/vk      ( 8550): Connection: keep-alive
D/vk      ( 8550): User-Agent: stagefright/1.2 (Linux;Android 4.2.2)
D/vk      ( 8550): Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate
D/vk      ( 8550): Accept: */*
D/vk      ( 8550): x-GETzip: supported
D/vk      ( 8550): Cache-Control: no-cache
D/vk      ( 8550): 
I/vk      ( 8550): URL http://cs1-50v4.vk-cdn.net/p1/7f2e4b808f5dac.mp3?extra=G38F1BvhVrlJWPJcV0Nzo9eejjznalTcvzU2RN1tPAouXsGMNj__oaOKoXtANhAc4ZjfJVYEL8TGhIp01X-Vte1OJjyw4w___365896___328011101
W/vk      ( 8550): java.io.IOException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
W/vk      ( 8550):  at java.io.File.createNewFile(File.java)
W/vk      ( 8550):  at com.vkontakte.android.cache.AudioCache$ProxyRunner.run(AudioCache.java:977)
W/vk      ( 8550):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java)
W/vk      ( 8550): Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: open failed: EACCES (Permission denied)
W/vk      ( 8550):  at libcore.io.Posix.open(Native Method)
W/vk      ( 8550):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.open(BlockGuardOs.java)
W/vk      ( 8550):  ... 3 more
```

Could you hint what can lead to such errors?

Comment: THis is not about programming android.  Try android.stackexchange.com

Comment: @GabeSechan, how can i move it?